java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Landroidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile in release version
I have NS project, this project working fine in Debug version, but in Release version filepicker show error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Landroidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.
I check Debug and production version, found 6 differences and add this 6 dependencies to app.gradle file to include exactly the same packages to bundle than in debug version
dependencies {
    'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'
    'androidx.cardview_cardview:1.0.0'
    'androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    'androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    'androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    'androidx.print_print:1.0.0'
}

But no result, debug version working fine, release version working with error. How is possible to fix this error?

I found mistake. This is wrong Gradle format + library what can not present in final release
correct Gradle format is
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 34
   buildToolsVersion "34"

   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 23
      targetSdkVersion 34
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0.0"
      generatedDensities = []
   }

   aaptOptions {
      additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
   }
}

